# iPhone/iPad/Android: Is there some api for testing web application accessibility?

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, accessibility

Instead of going through VoiceOver or similar software, I want a function which can take an element-id as parameter and return the alt text or label so that I can validate whether the text is correct.

Any other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `HttpClient` to fetch the HTML code from web, and use the `jsoup` library to parse the code, then find out the attributes of selected element. Download jsoup jar and put it into the `lib` directory of your project.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("..."); // ... is the string of HTML code
Elements inputElement = doc.select("#...").first(); // ... is the id of your element
String alt = inputElement.attr("alt") // select the "alt" attribute.
```